# JSR-303: after adding a constraint violation, additional empty one appears in constraint violations set

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have custom constraint:

```
@Target({FIELD, METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ConstraintComposition(CompositionType.AND)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CheckNumberValidator.class})
public @interface CheckNumberValid {
    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And validator for it (`isValid` method):

```
public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if(s.length() > 1 && s.length() < 3) {
            try {
                Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(s);
                if(something_wrong) {
                    constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{tooLargeNum}").addConstraintViolation();
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{numParseError}").addConstraintViolation();
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Messages are the following:

```
tooLargeNum="Too large num"
numParseError="Num parse error"
```

I have a class with one field annotated with `@CheckNumberValid`. After validation is completed I get two constraint violation messages: numParseError and empty one.

```
User number = new User("2d");

Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(number);
for (ConstraintViolation<User> constraintViolation : constraintViolations) {
    System.out.println(constraintViolation.getMessage());
}
```

The result is:

```
/empty string/
"Num parse error"
```

Here is what I see in debug:

[image: Multiple error for one violation]

Do I add constraint violation in incorrect way or what is wrong with it in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your are missing

```
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
```

which prevents the generation of violation with default message from the constraint annotation (which in your example is an empty string `String message() default ""`). That's why you get two violations - one is auto-generated and another one - is the one built with the call to the context method. So your validator implementation should probably look something like this:

```
    class CheckNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckNumberValid, String>{

         @Override
         public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
             if(value.length() > 1 && value.length() < 3) {
                 try {
                     Integer integer = Integer.valueOf(value);
                     if(something_wrong) {
                         context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                         context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{tooLargeNum}").addConstraintViolation();
                         return false;
                     }
                 } catch (Exception ex) {
                     context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
                     context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{numParseError}").addConstraintViolation();
                     return false;
                 }

             }
             return true;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I really missed. Thank you.